# IFS read in loop bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, ifs

I would like to iterate on a loop, my variable $_INFO on which I loop contains:

```
tcp/443
tcp/80
udp/54
```

I tried to parse my variable with this loop

```
_INFO=("tcp/443" "tcp/80" "udp/54")
for val in "$_INFO"; do
   IFS=/ read _PROTOCOL _PORT <<< $_INFO
   echo "protocol: $_PROTOCOL"
   echo "port: $_PORT"
done
```

I receive in output :

```
protocol: tcp
port: 443 tcp/80 udp/54
```

While I would like to receive in output:

```
protocol: tcp
port: 443
protocol: tcp
port: 80
protocol: udp
port: 54
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be of help. Thanks

Comment: To make your code work, just fix these mistakes: correct syntax for an array: `for val in "${_INFO[@]}"`, and read the right variable (`$val`, not `$_INFO`): `IFS=/ read _PROTOCOL _PORT <<< $val`. Now you will get the expected output.

Comment: @dan It's best to quote the here-string (i.e. `<<< "$val"` instead of just `<<< $val`), because some versions of bash had weird parsing bugs with unquoted variable references in that particular context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `awk` is ok:

```
$ echo "$_INFO" | awk -F\/ '{printf "protocol: %s\nport: %d\n", $1, $2}'
protocol: tcp
port: 443
protocol: tcp
port: 80
protocol: udp
port: 54
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` alone is enough, thanks to parameter expansion with removal of matching prefix or suffix pattern:

```sh
_INFO=("tcp/443" "tcp/80" "udp/54")
for val in "${_INFO[@]}"; do
  echo "protocol: ${val%/*}"
  echo "port: ${val#*/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to feed the whole loop with your input.

```
#! /bin/bash

_INFO='tcp/443
tcp/80
udp/54'

while IFS=/ read _PROTOCOL _PORT; do
  echo "protocol: $_PROTOCOL"
  echo "port: $_PORT"
done <<< $_INFO
```